# MonoTouch deterministic disposing cells

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

In our current app we need to perform some cleanup in the Dispose() of our custom UITableViewCells.

Unfortunately even though we call TableView.Dispose() our cells won't immediately get disposed. Instead, later on, the finalizer will call Dispose(false).
Since we are called by the finalizer we shouldn't perform our cleanup here: objects might be in a unpredictable state and the time when it occurs can't be determined.

From Microsoft documentation:

> The finalizer is called when the GC detects that an object is eligible for collection. This happens at some undetermined period of time after the resource is not needed anymore.

And also:

> If the method is invoked from the finalizer (disposing is false), other objects should not be accessed. The reason is that objects are finalized in an unpredictable order and so they, or any of their dependencies, might already have been finalized.

Is there a solution to have the Dispose() method of our custom cells be called when the tableview is disposed?

Comment: Maybe relying on Dispose() is the wrong approach here. You should know best when your UITableView is no longer needed and therefore just loop through its cells and do whatever cleanup you need to do and don't worry about disposing them and let that up to the GC later.

Comment: That's exactly what Dispose() pattern is for: performing clean up in a deterministic way. I don't want to rely on the finalizer it's exactly the opposite. In Winform when you Dispose() a control it will Dispose() it's child hierarchy. Same for any object in fact: if you dispose it, you can assume, if developed correctly, it will dispose all disposable encapsulated objects. I can loop through cells, that's for sure, but in my opinion it's a clunky way to achieve this.

Comment: Like @poupou already said: you cannot rely on the table disposing all cells (immediately).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to call Dispose on each individual cell when Dispose is called on the table itself, you need to handle this yourself:

1. Subclass UITableView.
2. Store all the cells you use in a list of cells in this class.
3. Override Dispose on the view, and call Dispose on each cell in the list.

Comment: Thanks Rolf I will do it that way then.

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewCell` are re-used (cached) by the `UITableView`. Calling `Dispose` on the table only removes the *managed* reference to the object. IOW there might still be **native** references to the table that will keep the cells alive longer.

It's not clear what kind of cleanup is required (that could not be done when the finalizer is executed). If it's basic UI code (i.e. your logic is elsewhere) then it should be fine (and you might be able dispose of your logic, managed-only, instances separately).

Comment: Hi Poupou thanks for the feedback. I updated my question to explain why it's not a solution to rely on the finalizer. Basically we don't know when it will happen and don't know if other objects are already garbaged. We need to be able to perform our clean up in a deterministic way. Maybe, due to cell reuse, we should implement something else but still we lack a solution here.